# addCommand using wrong prop in Monaco + Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, monaco-editor

Likely not specific to Monaco, but below is an example demonstrating the issue. I have a Vue 3 application that has state which is a list of objects. The application renders multiple components that contain an instance of a Monaco editor, and I'm passing in each state object to the components and using that state as a property within the component. I'm attaching a command to the editor in which case the property contains the incorrect state. It's using the last state object in the list. This is likely clearer using an example:

types.ts

```js
export type MyObj = {
    code: string;
};
```

App.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { type MyObj } from './components/types';
import CodeEditor from './components/CodeEditor.vue';

const myObjs = ref<MyObj[]>([
  { code: 'foo' },
  { code: 'bar' },
  { code: 'biz' },
])
</script>

<template>
  <CodeEditor v-for="obj in myObjs" :obj="obj" :key="obj.code" />
</template>
```

CodeEditor.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, onMounted, type PropType, ref } from 'vue';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
import type { MyObj } from './types';

const props = defineProps({
  obj: {
    type: Object as PropType<MyObj>,
    required: true,
  }
});

const editorContainer = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
    console.log('onMounted, code = ', props.obj.code);

    if (!editorContainer.value) {
        return;
    }

    const editor = monaco.editor.create(editorContainer.value, {
        value: props.obj.code,
        language: 'python',
        automaticLayout: true,
    });

    editor.getModel()?.onDidChangeContent(() => {
        console.log('Content changed, code = ', props.obj.code);
    });

    editor.addCommand(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter, () => {
        console.log('Cmd + Enter, code = ', props.obj.code);
    });
});
</script>

<template>
    <div ref="editorContainer" class="editor"></div>
</template>

<style>
.editor {
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Notice in this `CodeEditor` component, I'm attaching the following key command (Cmd + Enter):

```
editor.addCommand(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter, () => {
    console.log('Cmd + Enter, code = ', props.obj.code);
})
```

This is where the problem lies.

When rendering the application, as expected, the messages get logged from `onMounted` as:

```
onMounted, code = foo
onMounted, code = bar
onMounted, code = biz
```

However, when I execute the key command from each of the three editor, in order, I get:

```
Cmd + Enter, code =  biz
Cmd + Enter, code =  biz
Cmd + Enter, code =  biz
```

Which, `biz` is the last item in the list. Strangely enough, notice that I also attached a `onDidChangeContent` event to the editor too:

```
editor.getModel()?.onDidChangeContent(() => {
    console.log('Content changed, code = ', props.obj.code);
});
```

When entering a new character in the three editors, in order, I see the correct code from props:

```
Content changed, code =  foo
Content changed, code =  bar
Content changed, code =  biz
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This may be related to the following bug logged in the `monaco-editor` repo: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2947

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it. You could try to downgrade monaco to `0.31.1` and test the issue is fixed. Another workaround is to use actions instead of commands, as suggested in comments. Also, you should remove the `vue` tags. `vue`/`vuejs3` experts can't answer this question. Only a `monaco-editor` one could. Besides, nobody here will fix the bug for you. Your only chance is to wait for a fix or try the available workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that stumble across this question, the issue appears to be related to Monaco and not Vue. There is an [open bug](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2947) in Monaco when using `addCommand` when there are multiple instances of an editor on the same page. The suggestion in the bug report above is to use actions, if possible, as a work around. In the case of the code in the original question, using actions, it would become:

```
editor.addAction({
    id: 'execute',
    label: 'execute',
    keybindings: [monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter],
    run() {
        console.log('Cmd + Enter, code = ', props.obj.code)
    }
});
```

This appears to resolve the issue.